# How to filter a row and remove those values from a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the next DataFrame:

```
x = [{'name': 'a.1,b,c,d,e,a,f,g,h'}, {'name': 'b.1,c,a.1,d,e.1,g,a,h'}, {'name': 'b.1,d,e,a,f.1,c,r'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

I need to filter column -> 'name' and delete the values **a** and **a.1**, and to get the next result:

[image]

I will be grateful for help

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
df['name_1'] = [','.join([a for a in d.split(',') if a not in set(('a','a.1'))]) for d in df['name']]
```

You can also `apply` the very same function to the `'name'` column:

```
df['name_1'] = df['name'].apply(lambda row : ','.join([a for a in row.split(',') if a not in set(('a','a.1'))]))
```

Output:

```
                    name           name_1
0    a.1,b,c,d,e,a,f,g,h    b,c,d,e,f,g,h
1  b.1,c,a.1,d,e.1,g,a,h  b.1,c,d,e.1,g,h
2      b.1,d,e,a,f.1,c,r  b.1,d,e,f.1,c,r
```

Comment: You might want to use a `set` instead of a `tuple` to hold the items (`set(('a','a.1'))`) in case there are many more terms to search, this will make searching `O(1)`. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dataframe's [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function this:

```
def update(r):
    items = r.split(',')
    return ','.join(filter(lambda x: x != 'a.1' and x != 'a', items))
df['name_1'] = df['name'].apply(update)
df
```

Output:

```
    name    name_1
0   a.1,b,c,d,e,a,f,g,h     b,c,d,e,f,g,h
1   b.1,c,a.1,d,e.1,g,a,h   b.1,c,d,e.1,g,h
2   b.1,d,e,a,f.1,c,r   b.1,d,e,f.1,c,r
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df['name'] = df['name'].replace({'a.1,':'','a':''},regex=True).str.replace(',,',',')
```

---

```
              name
0    b,c,d,e,f,g,h
1  b.1,c,d,e.1,g,h
2  b.1,d,e,f.1,c,r
```

Comment: Just a note, your solution is actually the slowest of all (the valid ones) as `replace({'a.1,':'','a':''})` loops on the parameters to read again the string, it would be even worse with more items to check ;)

Comment: Thanks @mozway for the tip. Please keep giving them when you see something that can be improved. That's the whole point of being here. Can you explain what you mean? Is the issue that I run replace twice, or ```replace``` generally loops on the parameters (i.e. ```a.1```, ```a```) which makes it slow?

Answer (score 0):

Another regex option:

```
df['name'].str.replace(r"a\.1|a","").str.replace(r'(?<=,),|^,',"")
```

---

```
0      b,c,d,e,f,g,h
1    b.1,c,d,e.1,g,h
2    b.1,d,e,f.1,c,r
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['name_1'] = df['name'].str.split(',').apply(lambda cell_value: ",".join(filter(lambda x: x not in {'a', 'a.1'}, cell_value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that all proposed regex answers use two passes to achieve the goal.

Here is a regex answer that relies on a single expression:

```
# list of substrings to remove
# IMPORTANT: if an element is a left-aligned substring of another
# the substring should be ordered after the longer string
# here "a" is after "a.1"

remove = ['a.1', 'a']

import re
regex = '({0}),|,({0})'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, remove)))
df['name_1'] = df['name'].str.replace(regex, '', regex=True)
```

Alternative if group capturing is unwanted:

```
regex = '(?:{0}),|,(?:{0})'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, remove)))
```

Example:

```
                      name           name_1
0      a.1,b,c,d,e,a,f,g,h    b,c,d,e,f,g,h
1  b.1,c,a.1,d,e.1,g,a,h,a  b.1,c,d,e.1,g,h
2        b.1,d,e,a,f.1,c,r  b.1,d,e,f.1,c,r
```

Format of the generated regex:

```
'(a\\.1|a),|,(a\\.1|a)'

# or for the alternative
'(?:a\\.1|a),|,(?:a\\.1|a)'
```